# identifying set items

Tags: c++

I just asked a question involving `std::set` but after thinking about it some more, I think I've narrow down my problem to something simple.

I have a set of unique items. I'd like to create a vector where each element in the vector points to an item in the set.

So, I have a set of (unique) A objects:

```
class A
{
    int i;
};

std::set<A, compareclass> mySet;
```

and a vector of A*:

```
std::vector<A*> myVec;
```

`set::insert()` returns a pair which includes an iterator to the element (inserted or already existing) in the set. I could technically get it's address like so:

```
ret = myset.insert(A());
myVec.push_back(&(*ret.first));
```

I'm thinking that might not be a great idea, though. Is there any other way to allow a vector element to point to a specific object in the set?

Comment: An iterator into a set is only invalidated when/if you delete the item it points at. As such, why not just store iterators? But why do you want an array of pointers/iterators/whatever into a set anyway? That's not to say there's no possible use for such a thing, just wondering.

Comment: You may want to look at Intrusive Containers, like in Boost: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/intrusive.html - these let you have your cake and eat a muffin too

Comment: @JerryCoffin Part of my confusion was not knowing if the iterator could be invalidated or change if I added/deleted other set items or if it would remain good for the duration of the program.

Comment: @user974967: "The insert and emplace members shall not affect the validity of iterators and references to the container, and the erase members shall invalidate only iterators and references to the erased elements."

Comment: Excellent, you've eased my iterator anxiety. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`I'm thinking that might not be a great idea`, why do you think that? The only thing I see you is that you could do is to use something along the lines of a smart pointer instead of a plain pointer to clarify ownership, and avoid memory leak mistakes that come along with them.

Or like suggested by Jerry, iterators are even better!

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I'd allocate the objects on the heap, and would store smart pointers (e.g. `shared_ptr`) to them in both the set and the vector.

In my view this will drastically reduce the likelihood of memory- or pointer-related bugs. It would also decouple the lifetimes of the set and the vector.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like

```
 typedef std::shared_ptr<A> APtr

 std::set<APtr, compareClassThatTakesAPtr> aSet;
 aSet.insert(new A());

 std::vector<APtr> aVec;

 //...
 aVec.push_back(aSet.begin());
```

Now that they're on the heap, `set`/`vector` aren't managing instance of A directly. Instead you take responsibility for the fact that your `set` and `vector` all point to the same objects.